# How to get sub path segments in BaseX?

Tags: basex

Let's say I have these resources in a BaseX database called "myDB":

```
1/A/D/01.xml
1/A/E/02.xml
1/B/F/03.xml
1/B/G/04.xml
2/C/H/05.xml
```

Now I want all available sub path segments of a particular path in this database.

Example:

```
getSubPaths('myDB', '1/')
```

should return the sequence

```
('A', 'B')
```

Is there an XQuery function or another way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
declare function local:getSubPaths(
  $db    as xs:string,
  $path  as xs:string
) as xs:string* {
  distinct-values(
    for $doc in db:open($db, $path)
    return db:path($doc)
        => substring-after($path)
        => replace('/.*', '')
  )
};
```

Depending on your exact requirements, the function may need to be updated to also accept paths that may not end with a slash, to not return leaves (filenames), etc.